# How correctly set the condition under which the slider would work?

Tags: javascript, html

please tell me how to write the condition correctly? I need, if the screen of the monitor is 768 pixels, then this condition was triggered for the slider:

```js
document.querySelector('.slider__next').addEventListener('click', function() {
    offset = offset + 304;
    if (offset > 608) {
        offset = 0;
    }
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});
document.querySelector('.slider__prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
    offset = offset - 304;
    if (offset < 0) {
        offset = 608;
    }
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});
```

and if the screen of the monitor is 320 pixels, then this condition was triggered for the slider:

```js
document.querySelector('.slider__next').addEventListener('click', function() {
    offset = offset + 304;
    if (offset > 912) {
        offset = 0;
    }
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});
document.querySelector('.slider__prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
    offset = offset - 304;
    if (offset < 0) {
        offset = 912;
    }
    sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
});
```

I'm trying to do this, but for some reason it does not work correctly with a 320 pixels screen. the code works under the 768 pixel screen:

```js
if (window.innerWidth == 768) {
    document.querySelector('.slider__next').addEventListener('click', function() {
        offset = offset + 304;
        if (offset > 608) {
            offset = 0;
        }
        sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
    });
    document.querySelector('.slider__prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
        offset = offset - 304;
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = 608;
        }
        sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
    });
} else if (window.innerWidth == 320) {
    document.querySelector('.slider__next').addEventListener('click', function() {
        offset = offset + 304;
        if (offset > 912) {
            offset = 0;
        }
        sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
    });
    document.querySelector('.slider__prev').addEventListener('click', function() {
        offset = offset - 304;
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = 912;
        }
        sliderLine.style.left = -offset + 'px';
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*does not work correctly*"? Please be more specific...

Comment: this means that when I click on the slide scroll button, on a 320px screen, they scroll one at a time, and when the last slide is shown, the slides go back to the beginning. and when going to the 768px screen, the slides are scrolled to the last + white space is shown. that is, the code condition for screen 768 does not fire.